# React - Proper syntax for JSON parsing

Tags: reactjs, json, react-hooks

I am pulling in transaction details from `const details` and I need to pull out `brand` from the JSON `paymentResponse`. I am receiving an undefined error but everything in `let cardType` looks correct. What am I missing?

`let cardType = JSON.parse(orderDetails.paymentResponse).data?.payment_method_details?.card?.brand;`

The code:

```
 const [orderDetails, setOrderDetails] = useState({});
  
  const getOrderDetails = async () => {
    let data = {};
    data.orderId = params.id;
    const details = await orderApi.getOrderDetails(userAuthToken, data);
    if (details && details.data.success) {
      if (details.data.data.length > 0) {
        setOrderDetails(details.data.data[0]);
      } else {
        navigate('/');
      }
    } else {
      navigate('/');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (params.id) {
        setLoading(true);
        await getOrderDetails();
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        navigate('/');
      }
    })();
  }, [params.id]);
  //
  let cardType = JSON.parse(orderDetails.paymentResponse).data?.payment_method_details?.card?.brand;

  console.log(cardType);
```

[image]

The JSON structure where `brand` is:

```
{
   "data":{
      "payment_method_details":{
         "card":{
            "brand":"jcb"
         }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cam you share the full `orderDetails` and error message?

Comment: `if (orderDetails) let cardType = JSON.parse(orderDetails.paymentResponse...`
Cause your `orderDetails` is not avaiable once your component loads...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `orderDetails` object is empty when your component first loads, the `orderDetails.paymentResponse` is undefined, and trying to access its `data` property is throwing the error. You'd need to handle this undefined variable because `JSON.parse` cannot do that for you. Since you're already using the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator, changing that particular line as follows should get rid of the error:

```js
  let cardType = JSON.parse(orderDetails?.paymentResponse || "{}")?.data?.payment_method_details?.card?.brand;
```